# How to pass the input file path to argparse python?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to run the demo.py file in this repository, [Straight skeleton implementation in Python](https://github.com/Botffy/polyskel)

But when I try to run this I could not find any input file paths. Input files are inside examples folder but couldn't find a place to set the file path. When I run this script an error occurred saying some arguments are missing. I know that the missing argument is input file path but I don't know where to put it.
Appreciate your help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the repo which you have cloned or downloaded

```
cd /PATH/polyskel
```

and run following commands (any one of the below)

```
python demo.py examples/rectangle
```

or giving absolute path to the file

```
python demo.py /Users/chandu/Desktop/polyskel/examples/rectangle
```

Comment: If you don't mind, could you please tell me what is the format of the input files they have given?   
They are not in x,y format.

Comment: they are just text files and checking for patterns

`(Namespace(loglevel='WARNING', polygon_file=<open file 'examples/rectangle', mode 'r' at 0x10210f420>, verbose=False)`

Comment: Thanks for the replies.!
This code uses argparse and that's why I had to pass the image as an argument. If it is possible, Is there any way to pass it in code as an url?

Comment: yeah that code uses argparse that means whatever you wrote `python file.py arguments` main() function processes it. u can pass it as url for the image/text later you need to use requests module to read the data and work on algorithm part.